# why we use @Master type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

if we have a master page and a content page.so the content page @Page directive look like as

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" .... />
```

so , in order to access master page controls in content page we should have to use

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site1.Master" %>
```

so , my question is this why we use @MasterType directive when we already define in the @page directive that this content page is in the master page (here -- Site1.Master)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228274(v=vs.100)) you are defining the type of the `Master` property, which allows you to access the properties of your MasterPage derived class.

> Provides a way to create a strongly typed reference to the ASP.NET master page when the master page is accessed from the Master property.

As an example:

```
this.Master.SomePublicPropertyOfMaster = Value;
```

Comment: @Lloyd..will you  please tell me what do you mean by STRONGLY TYPE??since i am novice in programming so i have no idea about it...

Comment: It means the Type is explicitly declared, so you do not need to cast it ie: MyMasterPage masterPage = (MyMasterPage)this.MasterPage.

Comment: Link is dead. Try this one, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the @ MasterType directive with a type of `MyMasterPage` results in the following property definition in the code behind class:

```
public new MyMasterPage Master {
  get {
    return ({MyMasterPage})base.Master;
  }
}
```

This property definition is created by the [BuildMiscClassMembers](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Compilation/TemplateControlCodeDomTreeGenerator.cs,e00f6232b319229a,references) method of the `TemplateControlCodeDomTreeGenerator` class.