# Should I always use MasterType VirtualPath in child master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have many master pages inside an asp.net web forms project.

For example, **Sub.master** is using **Main.master** as master page and the sub master has following directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.master" %>
```

An experienced developer tells me to use it even I'm not accessing the Page.Master inside the sub master/page because it makes the page Strongly Typed. What are the pros and cons using this directive if any? Because I cannot decide if I should add it on every web form page too.

Answer (score 1):

It provides a way to create a strongly typed reference to the ASP.NET master page when the master page is accessed from the Master property.

See

- [why we use @Master type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946742/why-we-use-master-type)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(vs.80).aspx
- https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/asp-net-master-pages-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: So you're saying no advantage when not used?

Comment: Strongly types is always better. It reduces the chance for conversion errors. However if you do not need to access properties on the Master page then you don't really need it either.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks good but I never liked direct access to an object,control or method belonging to the master page.

I think there must be a standard of communication like event bubbling (master to child or child to master).

[<%@ MasterType **TypeName**="BaseMaster" %>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx#Attaching%20Master%20Pages%20Dynamically) seems to be good in establishing this standard.