# asp using master page variable in content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, public

I've read every post I can find on how to do this and tried them all.  I have a Master page called DNAStaff (at root) containing:-

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DNAStaff.master.cs" Inherits="DNAStaff" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
            <link href="~/Styles/DNA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

...............
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Masterpage code behind includes:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

public partial class DNAStaff : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string MyAccessLevel
    {
    get; set;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=NZ1;Initial Catalog=Intranet;Integrated Security=false;UID=IntranetAccess;PWD=*****";
        string sqlstring = @"select [MenuID], [Item], Target, SecLevel from [MENUS] ";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        int MainGroup;
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["userinfo"] != null)
            {
                MyAccessLevel = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userinfo"]["accessLevel"]);
            }
            else
            {
                MyAccessLevel = "1";
            }
    .........
```

The content page includes:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/DNAStaff.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="main" %>
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/DNAStaff.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    Set Primary Project
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>

enter code here
```

and the content page code behind contains:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string AccessLevel = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccessLevel = Master.MyAccessLevel;
        TextBox1.Text = AccessLevel;
    }
}
```

The line "AccessLevel = Master.MyAccessLevel" gives an error:-

> Error CS1061  'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 
>       'MyAccessLevel' and no extension method
>       'MyAccessLevel' accepting a first argument of type 'MasterPage' could be 
>       found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>       8_Live_main.aspx  D:\Development\dnanew.steelpencil.com\Live\main.aspx.cs 
>       13    Active

I want to set the variable MyAccessLevel in the MasterPage at load and read it in any content page. I'm obviously missing something, can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the Master Page like this.

```
Site1 master = ((Site1)(Page.Master));
TextBox1.Text = master.AccessLevel;
```

Where `Site1` is the class name of the Master Page (`public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage`)

However you should know that the Master Page_Load is initialized at a later stage in the Page Life Cycle than the Page. So when you access the value of `AccessLevel`, it will always be empty.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

Comment: Thanks - the line "Site master = ((Site)(Page.Master));" gives an error CS0246 "The type or namespace name "Site" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: @OrmondStock sorry i had to explain that better. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As in the content page already you have assigned the `MasterType` like below.

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/DNAStaff.master" %>
```

So now your child/content page can able to use/access the `master` layout including the `public` variable/properties  defined in the `master` page.

So now, as per your requirement, to access the `public` property(`AccessLevel`) defined in your `master` page and assign to the child/content page `textbox`, you need to write the below code

```
Site myMaster = ((Site)(Page.Master));
TextBox1.Text = myMaster .AccessLevel;
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Here are the more references about Master page and accessing the contents of master page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946742/why-we-use-master-type) should answer your question.
You must add

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/your page path" %>
```

directive to your page